# Writing a jQuery function to load a page with some variables

Tags: jquery, api, function

So made an api, that uses variables in an url to load an image. For example:

`api.php?apikey=1da654d1a654d1a5d4a5s1dad5789a4da&type=gif&image=1`

Now i want to write an jQuery function, that if i do something like this:

```
('#div').awnlapi( {
    apikey: 1da654d1a654d1a5d4a5s1dad5789a4da, 
    type: gif, 
    image: 1, 
    xhtml: false, 
    alt: this is some text 
});
```

But how can i make #div to fill with

`<img src="api.php?apikey=1da654d1a654d1a5d4a5s1dad5789a4da&type=gif&image=1" alt="this is some text">` (I don't use /> because xHTML was set to false in the example)

How can i do that? This is what i already got:

```
(function($){
                $.fn.awnlapi = function(options) {
                    var defaults {
                        apikey:,
                        type: 'gif',
                        image: '0'
                        xhtml: false,
                        alt: 'Visit mywebsite.com'
                    }

                    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

                });
            }
```

---

## Edit

So i started all over again and made this:

```
        (function($){
            $.fn.awnlapi = function(apikey, type, image, xhtml = false, alt) {
                if(xhtml == false){
                    var endtag = '>';
                }
                else
                {
                    var endtag = '/>';
                }

                $(this).html('<img src="http://api.alphenweer.nl/api.php?apikey='+ apikey +'&type='+ type +'&image='+image'" alt="'+ alt +'"'+ endtag);
            }
        }).jQuery;

        $('#image').awnlapi('adadnkandada6541da564d5ad1ad', 'gif', '1', false, 'This is alt!');
```

But this doesn't work neither, I get an blank page. Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at jQuery AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
Example:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "api.php",
   data: "apikey=1da654d1a654d1a5d4a5s1dad5789a4da&type=gif&image=1",
   success: function(msg){
     $("#div").html(msg);
   }
 });
```

You can set the variables before $.ajax ,like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var apikey = "1da654d1a654d1a5d4a5s1dad5789a4da";
    var type = "gif";
    var image=1;
    var option="xhtml";
    var alt="alt text";
    $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "api.php",
           data: "apikey="+apikey+"&type="+type+"&image="+image,
           success: function(msg){
           if(option=="xhtml") {
           var end=">"
           }
           else {
           var end="/>" 
           }
           var image = "<img src='"+msg+"' alt='"+alt+"'"+end;
             $("#div").html(image);
           }
         }); });
```

Comment: Yeah but how can i get the variable `options` in the `data` variable in `$.ajax`?

Comment: I don't understand.You want to send an AJAX call and get the information ,output by api.php or ?

Comment: @Iam3r4370 Please take another good look at my example and please read carefully.

Comment: You have an API ,which accepts params and outputs an image url?
You want to send variables to that api and get an image ,right?

Comment: Yes, and then i want to set the image url in an <img> tag, and if i look at the xhtml variable in `options` (an param in my function), i can choose between xhtml and html. If xhtml is false, the <img> tag ends with >, else with />, to keep the page valid of the user. And i also want to set the alt attribute using the alt option in `options`

Comment: Edited.You send the params like others.